# ServerSocket closing itself in AsyncTask [Android Wifi P2P Manager ]

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-asynctask, wifip2p

I am developing a android wifi -chat application .

Bit of Info about my app :
->A device calls startserver() to act as a server ,another device calls start client() to act as a client

What works:
->A Client can successfully send the data for the first time to the client, but not again and again

->I need to call startserver() again on first device , so that client can send data again .

The startserver() calls this Async task ,the following is its DoinBackgroundMethod

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {

        while(true) {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            StartMSG(client);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } finally {

        try {

            chatclient.changeserverrunning(false);
            if (serverSocket == null) {

            } else {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
//return null;
}

protected void StartMSG(Socket client){

    try {
        InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputstream);
        Message m = null;
        try {
            m = (Message) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (m != null) {
            if (m.gettype() == 1) {
                final String my_msg = m.getMessage();//Toast msg afterwards

        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Client Side Code :
It is started when the client hits send button and calls start client method .in which It sets up the Ip values before and bundles them and calls the message sending part as a Intent Service called FileTransferService

Its code is (abstracted) :

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    if(socket==null){
        socket = new Socket();
    }



    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_FILE)) {
        final String msg_type=intent.getExtras().getString(MESSAGE_TYPE);
        String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_ADDRESS);

        int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_PORT);

            try {
                    socket.bind(null);
                    socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);



                Message m = (Message) intent.getExtras().getSerializable(MESSAGE_INTENT_STR);
                final String my_message=m.getMessage();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);


                oos.writeObject(m);

                oos.flush();
                oos.close();

                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                ChatClient.copyFile(is, stream);

            } catch (IOException e) {

   } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            //socket.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: What `IOException` was caught?

Comment: I cannot Toast the Exception as I am running the server task on a Async Task , I can toast using handler.post ,but that would toast only static text ,I need to pass the Exception object to it to toast it , which I find confusing on how to do so

Answer (score -1):

You should try https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid and run the client from a service, from an asyntask it will always end up finishing.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @abhirulz yes look at the link in the answer the mConnection should be start form a service not a Asyntask, and the service should the started from the activity. this is the way u can use this library for a websocket